# Run GAP calculation for fixed time

Tags: gap

Is there a way to make gap stop a calculation after a certain amount of time?

I'm using an algorithm which is not guaranteed to terminate. But on (small) cases it will be either stop in under a second or run forever. 
In the moment I start the calculation and if it hasn't stop in, say 10 seconds, I break it manually with CTRL-C. But I would like to have a larger set of elements where the algorithm (probably) won't stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `CallWithTimeout` and `CallWithTimeoutList` - see [documentation here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap5.html#X782F88AC7B6DC4F9). They were [introduced in GAP 4.8](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap2.html). 
Some examples of usage are in [`tst/teststandard/timeout.tst`](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/stable-4.8/tst/teststandard/timeout.tst) file in your GAP installation. It should do what you want.

Comment: Ah, time to update to Version 4.8.