# Is it possible to give a time restriction to a GAP program?

Tags: algorithms, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I have written a GAP program that returns "true" or "false" as output.

I would like to modify the program in the following way:

If the computation is not finished after 20 seconds, then its output shall be "false".

Is this possible with GAP?

**Example:**

I would like to use this program in order to test if an ideal in a family of ideals has a certain property. If the computation does not finish after 20 seconds, then the ideal will most likely not have this property.

I would like to have a probabilistic program in that sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Revealing my ignorance, what is a GAP program and will the software have access (at various logical points in the code) to the system time?  Alternatively, will the software have access to the cpu time taken?  I know for sure that (for example) Java provides access to the system time, so one can measure at a given point in the code the elapsed system time that the program has been running.  It is unclear whether that is more *reliable* than measuring elapsed *cpu* time.  Further, while I suspect that (for example) Java (also) provides cpu time, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Whether or not you can do this in your program, you can probably do it in a  shell script , or bat file  that runs your program.

Answer (score 2):

In version 4.8 it is possible to call a function with a provided timeout as described in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750860/run-gap-calculation-for-fixed-time?rq=1). However, this functionality seems to have serious problems as described in [this](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/pull/1324) issue on GitHub and was therefore withdrawn in version 4.9 as stated [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap3_mj.html).

There is no convenient way (and with convenient I am rereferring to some sort of build in functionality) to achieve what you desire in the current version of plain GAP if we consider the [GAP reference](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html) as a complete description of its capabilities.

However, using the parallelization options described in [HPC-GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/hpc/chap0.html), we could start our calculation in a separate thread, while letting the main thread checking the exceeded time. I have never used it, so I am not sure if this would actually work. I tried it, but failed.

We could also embed the entire GAP system as a C library and call GAP functions in a C program. We could easily monitor the runtime within this program.

Also, and already mentioned by Ethan Bolker in the comments, you can write a GAP program and call it via a shell script. Monitoring the runtime there is also possible. The procedure is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418849/how-can-i-call-gap-functions-from-a-shell-script).

It might also be convenient in some cases to use the GAP interface in [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/gap.html).